# Changing the Window size of the new Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-terminal

As you've heard, the new Windows Terminal has been released. What I can't find is how to adjust the window size. In the old consoles, if you wanted to change the settings, it would give you a GUI, but with the new console, you need JSON commands. I've tried a couple of commands which were `initialCols` and `initialRows` but they didn't work for me, and I have tried to search for a solution for a while. Is there another way for me to adjust the window size or is it just not possible as in this point in time?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Open Terminal's `settings.json` file in a text editor (e.g. notepad), either from the Settings menu or from disk at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState` and add the following two lines (with the numbers you want to set instead of 92x60).

```
    "initialCols": 92,
    "initialRows": 60,
```

As noted in the [Global settings in Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/global-settings) documentation, those two lines should go under the root of the settings.json file, for example right above `profiles`.

```
    // A profile specifies a command to execute paired with ...
    "profiles":
    {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: example: https://gist.github.com/vchirikov/0b5843944f5016f58081efab6ae6a5d0

Comment: Note: the two commands should be under `profiles`, not on `defaults`.